# What does this "Message: Undefined property: stdClass" mean?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and php and I am currently encountering this error right now,I don't know where i went wrong. Should I add something on my foreach? Last time I encountered was an undefined property which was solved because of a misspelled word in my model now an stdClass? no words are misspelled this time. Can someone enlighten me with this problem?

The error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$blockcode
>
> Filename: views/v_schedule.php
>
> Line Number: 10

The view: v_schedule.php

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row){ ?>


                       <?php echo $row->blockcode;?> <br>
                       <?php echo $row->subjectcode;?> <br>
                       <?php echo $row->daystart;?> <br>
                       <?php echo $row->dayend;?>   <br>
                       <?php echo $row->stime;?>    <br>
                       <?php echo $row->sday;?> <br>
                       <?php echo $row->instructorname;?>   <br>
                       <?php echo $row->instuctorlastname;?>    <br>
                       <?php echo $row->roomcode;?> <br>
                       <?php echo $row->building;?> <br>

        <?php } ?>
```

controller: c_test.php

```
 function getSchedule() {
       $data['query'] = $this->m_test->result_getSchedule();
       $this->load->view('v_schedule',$data);
 }
```

model: m_test.php

```
function result_getSchedule()

    {
        $this->db->select('grades.studentid', 'grades.blockcode', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode','subjectblocking.daystart','subjectblocking.dayend', 'subjectblocking.stime','subjectblocking.sday','instructorinfo.firstname', 'instructorinfo.lastname', 'subjectblocking.roomcode','room.building');
        $this->db->from('grades');
        $this->db->join('subjectblocking', 'grades.blockcode=subjectblocking.blockcode');
        $this->db->join('instructorinfo', 'subjectblocking.instructorid=instructorinfo.instructorid');
        $this->db->join('room', 'subjectblocking.roomcode= room.roomcode');
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->where('studentid', '2013-F0218');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like `$row` does not contain a property called `blockcode`. Try adding `print_r($row); echo "<br /><br />";` in your `foreach` loop to see what each `$row` value contains. Chances are that you're missing the property...

Comment: Also you could take a look at different type of errors in php here http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php.

Comment: it would be better if you load your `m_test` with resulting values and then pass an instance of model to view in controller. It would better make it MVC.

Comment: @War10ck it tells me array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["studentid"]=> string(10) "2013-F0218" } }

Comment: @AsimAwan I thought what I was doing is mvc. model is where i placed all the queries, my foreach was just calling the selected rows that i want to retrieve in my database

Comment: The error is what it says - there is no blockcode in the $row object. In fact there is only studentid. You are only selecting 4 items and trying to echo 10. You need to select more columns and check your column names as seems like blockcode doesnt exist

Comment: Model is not exactly "where i placed all the queries" thing, but we do place queries there. Its holds the data in the form application needs, but you have model used only to run the query and `return $query->result();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake

```
$this->db->select('grades.studentid', 'grades.blockcode', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode','subjectblocking.daystart','subjectblocking.dayend', 'subjectblocking.stime','subjectblocking.sday','instructorinfo.firstname', 'instructorinfo.lastname', 'subjectblocking.roomcode','room.building');
//this is is not right way codeigniter select.
//it only selects studentid
//blockcode is not seleted that's why you got that error
```

this is the right way

```
 $this->db->select('grades.studentid , grades.blockcode , subjectblocking.subjectcode , subjectblocking.daystart , subjectblocking.dayend , subjectblocking.stime , subjectblocking.sday , instructorinfo.firstname , instructorinfo.lastname ,  subjectblocking.roomcode , room.building');
```

Hope this will solve your problelm

Answer (score 0):

There are two blockcode columns in grades and subjectblocking tables.

You should change your sql in m_test.php like this :

```
 $this->db->select('grades.studentid', 'grades.blockcode as block_code', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode','subjectblocking.daystart','subjectblocking.dayend', 'subjectblocking.stime','subjectblocking.sday','instructorinfo.firstname', 'instructorinfo.lastname', 'subjectblocking.roomcode','room.building');
```

And you should change $row->blockcode variable as $row->block_code in v_schedule.php

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First I also used the code as above and I got the same error.

```
$this->db->select('grades.studentid', 'grades.blockcode as block_code', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode','subjectblocking.daystart','subjectblocking.dayend', 'subjectblocking.stime','subjectblocking.sday','instructorinfo.firstname', 'instructorinfo.lastname', 'subjectblocking.roomcode','room.building');
```

But by changing

```
$this->db->select('grades.studentid, grades.blockcode as block_code, subjectblocking.subjectcode,subjectblocking.daystart,subjectblocking.dayend, subjectblocking.stime,subjectblocking.sday,instructorinfo.firstname, instructorinfo.lastname, subjectblocking.roomcode,room.building');
```

I solved the error.

Better if we can give a single name for `grades.studentid` as `studentID` then we can directly call the:

```
echo $query->studentID;
```